# install icinga2 and icinga-web in different servers

Tags: icinga

I followed [this tutorial](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/snapshot/chapter-2.html) to install icinga2 on Sientific Linux and it works fine. What I need to do now is to install icinga2 in a server, the database in other server and icinga-web in an other one. All servers are within the same local netrwork. Is that possible and how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean of **this tutorial**?

Comment: @masegaloeh sorry I forgot the link. Added it.

Answer (score 3):

1. host1 runs icinga2
2. host2 runs the mysql db
3. host3 runs icinga web

regarding the network connections

- host2 listens on port 3306 (mysql), accepts read/write connections from host1 (write) and host3 (read)
- host1 listens on port 22, accepting incoming command pipe calls from host3 (if icinga web should be able to do so)
- host3 listens on port 80, serving icinga web

The IdoMysqlConnection in Icinga2 needs to be configured to point to host = "host2", port = "3306". Icinga Web databases.xml needs to be edited to point to the ido backend dsn for "host2:3306". Details on the documentation.

Comment: Can you please point to a detailed documentation on how to achieve this. How do I point the Icinga2 web to icinga2?. Likewise what file needs to change to point Icinga 2 to the separate host running the database?

Answer (score 1):

For the icingaweb2 to connect to backend server icinga2, you should setup icingaweb2 transport to use icinga2 api (enabling api, and creating api user is required on icinga2). Documentation for icingaweb2 transport can be [seen here](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icingaweb2/latest/modules/monitoring/doc/05-Command-Transports/).

For connecting to monitoring database, you may follow the default setup, replacing localhost with the proper box hosting the Database Backend, as [shown here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-icinga-and-icinga-web-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Just refer to the IDO section

Hope it helps